# Is there a concept of a middleware in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to do some pre and post processing of requests like handling authentication, loading contextual data, performance timings and things like that. Coming from Django there's a concept of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` that lets me handle the request in various stages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Currently it seems like each Controller has to do the same setup and load, in the constructor which isn't ideal because if the constructor fails, the class doesn't get initialized which has subtle but important consequences. I want to move this global handling to a global place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using codeigniter hook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not.
This might be helpful.
[Codeigniter forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65554.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use hooks for this, Edit your application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                                        'class'    => 'Autologin',  
                                        'function' => 'cookie_check', 
                                        'filename' => 'autologin.php',  
                                        'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon this question so even tho it has been 6 years since this question was asked, I am answering in case it helps anybody else like me.

I have found CodeIgniters has "filters" which can be used for that same purpose:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html?highlight=filters

Comment: I believe these were only added with codeigniter 4, so it won't be applicable on older apps running codeigniter 3 or lower

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not middleware routing structure in any codeigniter framework until now. But some guys has written a bunch of code to implement that.
[I have found it usable for some purposes](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-70497.html)